# How to write comprehension list in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, list-comprehension

I want to transform this :

```
     for _ in range(3):
         number = random.randint(1, 2)  # choosing a random waiting time for seconds
         p = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something, args=(number,))
         p.start()
         process.append(p)
```

Into this:

```
 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = [(number,executor.submit(do_something, number)) for number in range(10) number=random.randint(10)]
```

I don't know how to do it well and I have this error:

```
results = [(number,executor.submit(do_something, number)) for number in range(10) number=random.randint(10)]
                                                                                      ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried to put **()** and **[]** and even **,** I don't know what to try

Comment: I forgot to tell that I've put "import random" The problem is with how I've writed the comprehension list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import concurrent.futures
import random

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    results = [(number, executor.submit(your_function_here, number)) for number in [random.randint(1, 2) for _ in range(3)]]
```

Make sure to replace **your_function_here** with the actual function you want to execute.

I believe this is what you are looking for achieving the parallel execution you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you so much ! It's exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it in a cleaner and more readable way to separate the random number generation and process submission into two steps.

```
 import concurrent.futures
 import random

 def do_something(number):
# Your do_something function implementation here
pass

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
random_numbers = [random.randint(1, 2) for _ in range(3)]
results = [(number, executor.submit(do_something, number)) for number in 
random_numbers]
```

First, generate the random numbers in a separate line, and then use those numbers in the comprehension to submit the tasks to the ProcessPoolExecutor.